# Covariant derivative and vector fields along a curve

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, vector-fields, geodesics

I have to prove a relation that involves the covariant derivative induced by the Levi-Civita connection.

With the reference on

> [N. Straumann General Relativity](http://archive.org/details/GeneralRelativity/page/n82/mode/1up)

Given $T=\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}$ and $S=\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta}$ two vector fields along a geodesic $\gamma$, then
$$\nabla_T S=\nabla_S T$$
To do this I have thought:
$$\nabla_T S=\nabla_T \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta}=\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}(\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta})+\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial s}\nabla_ T \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta} $$
$$\nabla_S T=\nabla_S \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}=\frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial s}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta}(\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha})+\frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial t}\nabla_ S \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha} $$
I don't how to further to prove that these two above are equal, can you help me?

Comment: I think there may be a typo in your question. What are you saying about the geodesic $\gamma$?  For two vector fields $T$ and $S$, $\nabla_T S \neq \nabla_S T$ in general.

Comment: This is the reference https://archive.org/details/GeneralRelativity/page/n82/mode/1up

Comment: The two vector fields mentioned by your reference *commute* with one another, which is a critical detail you need to add to your question.  Are you confused as to why those two specific vector fields commute, or are you confused as to how to show that $\nabla_S T = \nabla_T S$ given the fact that they commute?

Comment: Yes sorry maybe I have not been so clear in the question. I want to prove that they commute as I have tried to do in the attempt described above